# Creating custom widgets in android studio?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio

Android Studio allows to design the GUI with widgets like Radiobutton, small button, checkbox etc, which has its own properties.

I am very new to android and I want to add new widgets in android studio by extending current widgets/views (for example, adding new settings for Seekbar) (if possible). Any idea, how can I implement it?

I know that I can create custom views by xml for the app. But I want to add that in android studio.

Comment: Check this link to know about creating widgets...https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Comment: I want to add widget in android studio, its different than the android app widget.

Comment: RadioButton is not a Widget, it is a View (even if it is in the widget package).
You want to know how to devlop a custom View, or you want to know how to add the drag and drop button to add your custom View in Android Studio GUI ?

Comment: I have made a custom view here. It might give you an basic idea on how to make a custom view and how to add it to your xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929075/get-four-co-ordinates-of-rectangle-canvas-android/29984384#29984384

Comment: @Blusky You got it exactly. I want to know, how to add the drag and drop button to my custom View in Android Studio GUI.

Answer (score 1):

On the "View Editor" screen, on the "Palette" tab, go to "Custom" section and select "CustomView". Then, select your Custom View, and drag and drop it to your user interface.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking it now.